# Personal VPN sub-network accessible through Work VPN?

Tags: router, vpn, subnet, private-vlan

I currently access my work network via Cisco VPN.

At work, I have my own three computers and NAS on a personal dedicated router using my own DHCP. For several reasons, I do not want these computers to be accessible to others on the broader work network.

However, because of this router, I cannot access my work computers from home. I was thinking, can I use a VPN router for this personal work network? I imagine I could first connect to Cisco VPN, and then connect to my personal VPN through the dedicated VPN router.

Would something like this work? Is VPN the correct approach?

Comment: You would need to provide a diagram of how things are connected and sanitized configs from the routers/VPN appliances involved for us to better understand how your environment is designed and to propose an answer about how you could accomplish this.

Comment: Probably not.   You won't be able to configure a "VPN inside a VPN."  You should check with your IT staff as to the best approach.